# how to read input again in echo

Tags: linux, shell-script

hello im really new at bash scripting,

im trying to make a script to check files on a server, so i did it but it won't ask for new student name, how do i tell it to read my input again ? also how to tell it to grab the server names from a file ?

```
while read -p 'Enter the ip address for the server: ' ip_addr && [[ -z "$ip_addr" ]] ; do
 echo "No-no, please, no blank IP address!"
done

while [[ !  "$ip_addr" =~ ^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$ ]]; do
    read -p "No-no not an valid IP. Re-enter: " ip_addr
done

while read -p 'Enter the student name: ' student_name && [[ -z "$student_name" ]] ; do
 echo "No-no, please, no blank student Name!"
done


while read -s -p 'Enter password: ' password && [[ -z "$password" ]] ; do
 echo "No-no, please, no blank passwords!"
done

y=$student_name
x=$y
####################################################################

sshpass -p "$password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $ip_addr "x=$y"  /bin/bash << "EOF"
                        sudo su - $x


ls -lrth ~/$USER/*DAT* | tail -10

pwd

ls -lrth ~/$USER/*PDF* | tail -10


##############################


while read -p 'Enter New student  Name: ' new_student _name && [[ -z "$new_student_name" ]] ; do
 echo "No-no, please, no blank student name!"
done

cat /opt/$USER/$new_student_name.txt

exit 0

fi

EOF
```

Comment: You have a `if` without a `then`... Is this the true paste of your script?

Comment: so i just want for echo to read my input again and do the cat for the new input "new student name"

Comment: Related: [Prompt for username until name not found in file](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/510119)

Comment: Your last `read` reads the _two_ variables `new_student` and `_name`. The space between the two is probably a typo.

Comment: thanks i edit it but its still not asking me for the input it just echo ""No-no, please, no blank student name!" but if i add another EOF before echo it will stop and ask me for input but it will go back to the original user :\

Comment: Well, what is the `read` reading? It reads from standard input. What's on standard input? It's inherited from the `bash` process you start with `ssh`. What's on the `bash` process' standard input? Well, it's the here-document containing the `read` loop. So the last `read` reads from the here-document, not from the user. You can't read from the user on standard input in a shell script being sent to the standard input of the shell.

Comment: You also have a trailing `fi` towards the end of the here-document that I can't see a corresponding `if` statement for, and what do you expect your `sudo su - $x` would do (hint, normally it would start an interactive shell; this is probably not what you want here).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a dollar at the cat line.

```
cat /opt/$USER/$new_student_name.txt
```

Comment: oh thanks i did add it but it ignore the echo before it, so it won't take my new student name, what do i need to add before echo so it stop and read my command ?